# Can I run a single-node K3S cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I am aware of the consequences and issues with running a single-node cluster. However, I'm still curious if it's possible. I plan on setting everything up myself.

In other words, can I run the control plane and a worker node on the same physical machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please let me elaborate with this topic:

> "In other words, can I run the control plane and a worker node on the same cluster"

From k3s docs:

> A server node is defined as a machine (bare-metal or virtual) running the k3s server command.
>
> A worker node is defined as a machine running the k3s agent command.
> Adding more agent will create more worker nodes  to run your application.

In this concept one master node (***running k3s server command*** and additional agent nodes ***running the k3s agent command***) still create one cluster with single control plane. However you can extend this approach by creating High-Availability K3s Server with multiple server(control planes) and agents nodes.

As per k8s docs:

> [**Control Plane Components**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#control-plane-components):
>
> - kube-apiserver,
> - etcd,
> - kube-scheduler,
> - kube-controller-manager,
> - cloud-controller-manager,

As I can see there is also an option to run k3s wiht multiple agents on single machine Using Docker as the Container Runtime - [K3d](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/advanced/) ( (K3s in Docker) and docker-compose.

As an alternative please follow:

- [Learning environment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/) using Kind, and minikube
- [Production environment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/) using kubeadm, kops,kubespray

Comment: Ah sorry, I actually meant a control plane and worker on the same physical machine. I'll correct my question.

Comment: So as stated in the answer you can use k3d (k3s in Docker) or create server as vm and additional agent as vm on the same physical machine.

Comment: Can I have two separate machines with K3D that are part of the same cluster though? Is that still possible?

Comment: I did not try but looking into the docs you can find - to run the agent only in Docker, "alternatively the docker run" and there you should provide server_url. So it looks if server is accessible via network it should work.

Answer (score 6):

When you install K3s with the curl script like below, the node will be both a server and agent.

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
```

So, by default the server and agent are deployed together on the same node.
Answered here https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1279#issuecomment-574332274 by David Nuzik (Rancher Labs (SUSE) Project Manager)

Answer (score 1):

Very much so, of course. The consequences are simply that you have no HV as the respective redundancy is missing.

The official documentation even has a section on setting up a [single control-plane cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

(When talking about "the same physical machine" I would *highly* encourage you to setup two VMs on there, one for the control plane node, one for the worker.)